# Numerous wp-include files needed for simple php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning php in a sandbox. I have written a plugin and it works...till now.

So I am now wanting to save the options into the database and these settings are specific to the user so I am using:

```
 update_user_meta
```

Well of course it said it needed user.php so after reading / learning how to include a file I added it. Well now it is dependat on plugin.php which has a dependency on functions.php which... so I'm up to four now. I must be doing something worng?

```
include(__DIR__.'/../wp-includes/functions.php');
include(__DIR__.'/../wp-includes/meta.php');
include(__DIR__.'/../wp-includes/plugin.php');
include(__DIR__.'/../wp-includes/user.php');
```

What I have is a plugin in the admin with a form for some settings. When button clicked form is posted to a php page for processing....it is this page (in wp-admin) that has the never ending include file list.

Is this to be expected or am I doing something wrong that these base wordpress libraries aren't available to my plugin?

TIA

Comment: did you check include()'s return value for boolean false? Maybe you've got the wrong path there.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. You should have this in a plugin file within `wp-content/plugins/mypluginname`, then you should have a base file with the same plugin name as your php file, `mypluginname.php`, then within this file, should contain your core php and wordpress logic. This hooks you into the wordpress core and stops the requisite for using `require_once('/wp-load.php');` which, incidentally, is the hack you're looking for.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy...I have my php file with plugin definition and gui html in plugin dir. My post page is in the admin...so you are saying both need to be in the plugin folder...if that is correct how do I specify in the form post as fiddler told me this <form method="post" action="firstplug_options.php"> was looking in admin...so I put it there?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy DOn't forget to make your comment an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question should be within a plugin.

The core structure is:

```
/wp-content
    /plugins
        /mypluginname
            /mypluginname.php
```

Then at the very least, `mypluginname.php` should contain the core code of the plugin, and any other php/wordpress logic you wish to have.

The plugin its self can be declared with the following:

```
/* 
Plugin Name: Custom plugin
Plugin URI: http://domain.tld
Version: 1.0
Description: A custom plugin
Author: You 
*/
```

Further, you can work around this and leverage core WP functions from external .php files that are not within the application by using `require_once('/wp-load.php');` within your files. **Note** I do not recommend this method, it is just a direct answer to your question, but not the correct one.